# url rewrite rules with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am new in writing url rewrite rules. Can you help me in writing rewrite rules. My current browser url is

```
http://localhost/live/match-page.php?mid=770&sid=7
```

My anchor tag for that url is given below

```
<a target='_blank' href="match-page.php?mid=<?php echo $rec->ID?>&sid=<?php echo $rec->stream_id?>" style="color:#ffae00;">  <?php echo $rec->CatName; ?> - <?php echo $rec->Title; ?> </a>
```

How I edit `.htaccess file` then I show my browser url like given bellow here:

```
http://www.cricmelive.tv/live/177/south-africa-v-india-test-live-streaming
http://www.cricmelive.tv/live/Basketball-live-streaming
```

how make anchor tage for url rewrite mode?

It is true that I made new queries for it? And pass to the database. If it is possible how do it.

Comment: Do you need both `mid` and `sid`

Comment: yes I need both @AbhishekAgrawal

Answer (score 1):

I hope these help. I'm a little confused though, you say you need both `mid` & `sid` yet the examples above are different ~ one has both the `mid` and `sid` parameters yet the other only has one, presumably `sid`

```
#htaccess

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^live/(.+)$ live/match-page.php?sid=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^live/([0-9]+)/(.+)$ live/match-page.php?mid=$1&sid=$2 [NC,L]


/* php */
/* Match first style rewrite rule */
echo "<a target='_blank' href='/live/{$rec->stream_id}' style='color:#ffae00;'>  {$rec->CatName} - {$rec->Title} </a>";

/* match second style rewrite rule */
echo "<a target='_blank' href='/live/{$rec->ID}/{$rec->stream_id}' style='color:#ffae00;'>  {$rec->CatName} - {$rec->Title} </a>";
```

There are two ways in which you can use `urlrewrite` - one as shown here where you generate your links as shown to match the pattern set in the rewrite rule and the other method is to use the links as you had them originally and use apache to make the ugly querystring into the new, pretty url. For examples of how to do the latter, have a look at some of the posts by [Anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) ~ he is a master!

Comment: let me try it. @RamRaider

Comment: In case original url [basic links](http://localhost/live/match-page.php?mid=770&sid=7) every thing ok as see in print scr: (prntscr.com/9ceyxw) but in url rewrite code, I think don't apply css file why, check in print scr:   (prntscr.com/9cf09d) where my url-rewrite code is : RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+)$ match-page.php?mid=$1&sid=$2 [NC,L] its work fine @RamRaider

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to htaccess file

```
 Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^/?live/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /match-page.php?mid=$1&sid=$2 [L]
```

On match-page.php, you can get `mid` and `sid`, assuming you add url like `http://www.cricmelive.tv/live/770/7/Basketball-live-streaming`

**EDIT**

Add this code to htaccess file

```
 Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^/?live/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /match-page.php?mid=$1&sid=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Then how make anchor tage for it? @RamRaider in match-page.php file to create link for it.

Comment: @mc120400429 is this comment for me?

Comment: oh I can understand, let me try for it  @Abhishek Agrawal

Comment: no it for RamRaider by mistake I past it here @Abhishek Agrawal

Comment: I try with your both code, put into the htaccess file and hit the browser with url:    http://localhost/live/770/7/Basketball-live-streaming. it does not work @Abhishek Agrawal

Comment: It work with the url:    http://localhost/live/770/7/south-africa-v-india-test-live-streaming. when I rewrite it as:   RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/? match-page.php?mid=$1&sid=$2 [NC,L]

Comment: @mc120400429 basically both are the same url

Comment: it works with code:    RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/ match-page.php?mid=$1&sid=$2 [NC,L] but not work for RewriteRule ^live/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/ match-page.php?mid=$1&sid=$2 [NC,L] why ? thanks to reply again and again @Abhishek Agrawal

Comment: @mc120400429, Actually your url is http://localhost/live/match-page.php?mid=770&sid=7 and I read it wrong by mistake. my code will internally redirect you to http://localhost/match-page.php?mid=770&sid=7 which is different from the url given here. I forgot to remove 'live' in my code. that is why it's not working. Sry for that.

Comment: In case original url every thing ok as see in print scr: http://prntscr.com/9ceyxw but in url rewrite code, I think don't apply css file why, check in print scr http://prntscr.com/9cf09d @Abhishek Agrawal

Comment: @RshidMukhtar use full path for your css, images, and JS files. Also please accept an answer, so it can help other users

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is how can you replace your current url patterns with a cleaner scheme (clean urls).

Your match page logic behind the scenes is most likely using 'mid' and 'sid' to do some kind of database lookup for the results.

Minimal change could be to change to a new url format like this:

```
http://www.example.com/live/MID/SID/text-descriptor
http://www.example.com/live/770/7/south-africa-v-india-test-live-streaming
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^live/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/ match-page.php?mid=$1&sid=$2 [L]
```

Then change your links to output the new pattern:

```
$href = '/live/' . $rec->ID . '/' . $rec->stream_id . '/' . $rec->text; // text from category or title (isn't needed by script.)
```

Comment: In case original url every thing ok as see in print scr:    [link](prntscr.com/9ceyxw)    but in url rewrite code, I think don't apply css file why, check in print scr    [link](prntscr.com/9cf09d)    @Progrock why? thanks to reply

Comment: @mc120400429 , probably because you are using relative URL paths for the CSS.   So the browser is likely trying to now find the CSS in /live/123/456/ or similar (check browser tools/network/assets).  Change your CSS path to an absolute from the root of your site.  So instead of 'css/site.css' use '/css/site.css'.

Comment: thanks to reply @Progrock, you guess right, I check it from `tools/network/css` status code is ok 200 and relative path is wrong path (http://localhost/live/330/4/templatemo_style.css). I change it `templatemo_style.css` to `/templatemo_style.css` but its not response how do it? I am sending you screen shot for it. [see in print screen shot](http://prntscr.com/9cgskp)

Comment: Given your path above: `/tools/network/css/templatemo_style.css`.

Comment: yes? what mean that path `/tools/network/css/templatemo_style.css` ? I check it with Inspect element from broswer I put it as but not work

Comment: I can understand what you are saying. I try it with `/` in first of all path like as `/templatemo_style.css` @Progrock but not work

Comment: Sorry, I understand now!  The relative path was being rewritten and passed to the php script, that's why you got a 200.  Just make sure the absolute path to the style sheet resolves.